# error in Sign with Google+ in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, google-api, omniauth, gmail-api

I am trying to implement sign in with google or any other social network in rails. I am already followed the Codeplace tutorial with http://r12---sn-cvh7kn7y.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?sparams=dur,ei,expire,id,i

I faced the following problem

```
 Error: invalid_request

Missing required parameter: client_id

Learn more

 Request Details
  access_type=offline
 scope=email profile
response_type=code
redirect_uri=http://localhost:9292/auth/google_oauth2/callback
state=2f6a1b1d2e0a2fb1c75647a6d145efa907c3ee9038a8bb54
client_id=
```

My related code are -
omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
provider :google_oauth2,ENV['238730796202-.com'],ENV['TyqJqfiOJLoLgqRRGgTIynxt']
 provider :facebook, ENV['1585034338471672'],ENV['3211b382a1636bdc747d37921aab2a90']
 end
```

sessioncontroller.rb

```
 class SessionsController < ApplicationController

def create
    auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    puts auth
    session[:omniauth] = auth.except('extra')
    user = User.sign_in_from_omniouth(auth)
    session[:user_id] = user_id
    redirect_to root_url, notice:"Sign In"
end
def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    session[:omniauth] = nil
    redirect_to root_url, notice:"Sign OUT"
end
end
```

user.rb

```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.sign_in_from_omniouth(auth)
    find_by(provider: auth['provider'], uid: auth['uid'])||   
    create_user_from_omniauth(auth)
end

   def self.create_user_from_omniauth(auth)
      create(
    provider:auth['provider'],
    uid:auth['uid'],
    name:auth['info']['name']

    )
end
end
end
```

can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per error encountered, `client_id` is missing.

Try the basic steps given in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps) wherein to obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials from the Google API Console by doing this:

> Visit the Google API Console to obtain OAuth 2.0 credentials such as a `client ID` and `client secret` that are known to both Google and your application.

Please also try enabling the **"Contacts API"** and **"Google+ API"** via the Google API console. As noted in this [GitHub post](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2), if these are not enabled, you will receive `OAuth2::Error(Error: "Invalid credentials")` stating that access is not configured when you attempt to authenticate.

Please try going through the given GitHub post, [OmniAuth Google OAuth2 Strategy](https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2) for important details.